# S3 object creation events dropped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue, a lambda, and many S3 buckets.

I have a system setup like so:

1. S3 buckets are configured to send object creation events to SQS
2. Lambda consumes these events from the SQS

This was working as expected, until the volume of these events grew very large. Now, I am noticing a lot of events are simply gone. I know this because I can see that objects were created in S3, but the event was never received by my lambda.

The event was dropped somewhere between S3 -> SQS <- Lambda (the lambda never receives the event message, so am assuming it was never queued)

**How can I investigate if S3 object creation events are dropped when configured to be sent to SQS?**

Comment: Are events triggered for  s3:ObjectCreated:* or just s3:ObjectCreated:Put? Are you sure the Lambda functions were never triggered (or could they have been triggered but failed, retried, and eventually were cancelled)?

Comment: @jarmod It is `s3:ObjectCreated:*`, and I am quite sure that lambda is never triggered, because I have a log statement to identify the source at the very start of the lambda. This is what raised my suspicion that events are lost.

Comment: SQS >> Lambda *sometimes* (depending on message arrival timing and size of the queue) sends multiple messages from the queue to a single Lambda invocation unless otherwise configured.  If you are only looking at the first element, this would explain the "missing" messages.